# Highcharts shared tooltip formatter doesn't get passed all points

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart which displays 3 series of data initially.

A shared tooltip formatter is used for the initial 3 series and this works correctly.

However after adding 2 additional series to the chart, it seems that when the formatter function is called it gets passed points on either the original 3 series or the 2 new ones.

The result of this is that I see one tooltip for the 2 new series when mousing over a point belonging to one of them, and I see the shared tooltip for the 3 original series when mousing over a point belonging to one of those.

What I want is for the formatter to be passed points for all series and to just have one tooltip for all points.

The formatter code looks like this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var s = [],
            addedDateLabel = false;

        console.log("In tooltip formatter", this);

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            var date = new Date(point.x),
                month = config.monthNames[date.getMonth()],
                year = date.getFullYear();

            if (addedDateLabel === false){
                s.push('<span><strong>' + month + ' ' + year + '</strong></span><br><br>');
                addedDateLabel = true;
            }

            s.push('<span style="color:' + point.series.color + ';font-weight:bold;">'+ point.series.name +' : \u00a3'+
                CurrencyFormatting.formatValue(point.y.toFixed(2)) +'<span><br>');
        });

        return s.join('');
    },
    shared: true
}
```

The console log in the above shows the following in the console:

[image: Console output]

Where you can clearly see that sometimes there are 2 points and sometimes 3.

I have tried calling `redraw()` on the chart after adding all the series but that doesn't seem to help.

I'm aware that I could probably just destroy the chart and create it again from scratch but would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: As you can see - you have different `x` values. To get points from all series you need to have **exactly** the same `x` value.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm implementing a line chart with 2 lines in multiple locations and in some cases, the tooltip formatter receives only 1 point on hover even though the tooltip shared option is set to true. For eg. I have a chart with 2 values in the series and the tooltip formatter receives both the points for the first point on hover but receives only 1 point on the hover for the second point. I cant seem to understand the issue! Any suggestions?